# Error - "No LuaRocks module found for fb.python"

Tags: lua, ubuntu-16.04, torch, luarocks

I am trying to implement a library which is a [Github project on 3D reconstruction using a single image](https://github.com/AaronJackson/vrn) in `Ubuntu 16.04`. I have installed all dependencies. I have checked if each dependency is correctly installed with help from Google searches and stackoverflow.

But, when I am executing the `./run.sh` as mentioned in the Github page, I get the following error.

```
/home/username/torch/install/bin/luajit: /home/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: /home/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: module 'fb.python' not found:No LuaRocks module found for fb.python
no field package.preload['fb.python']
no file '/home/username/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/fb/python.lua'
no file '/home/username/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/fb/python/init.lua'
no file '/home/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/fb/python.lua'
no file '/home/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/fb/python/init.lua'
no file './fb/python.lua'
no file '/home/username/torch/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta1/fb/python.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/fb/python.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/fb/python/init.lua'
no file '/home/username/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/fb/python.so'
no file '/home/username/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/fb/python.so'
no file '/home/username/torch/install/lib/fb/python.so'
no file './fb/python.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/fb/python.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
no file '/home/username/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/fb.so'
no file '/home/username/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/fb.so'
no file '/home/username/torch/install/lib/fb.so'
no file './fb.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/fb.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'

stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'error'
/home/username/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: in function 'require'
main.lua:8: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'dofile'
...name/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
[C]: at 0x00405d50
ls: cannot access '*.txt': No such file or directory
```

### This issue is in Torch directory and not in the project.

So please guide me how I can resolve it or what could have gone wrong.

P.S. I am new to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Torch first. `th and luarocks` both commands will be available after you install Torch, see [Torch](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: I have installed and verified my installation.